# If a curve in a regular surface is smooth, is the corresponding curve in the parameterization space also smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a regular surface and $\gamma: (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth curve with $\mathrm{im}( \gamma) \subset \Sigma$, and $\gamma (0) = p$. Let $\sigma : U \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \Sigma$ be a parameterization of $\Sigma$ near $p$ (so it's smooth as a map to $\mathbb R^3$). Define the map $\Gamma: (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathbb R^2$ via $\Gamma(t) = \sigma^{-1}(\gamma(t))$, i.e. $\Gamma$ is the curve in the parameterization plane corresponding to $\gamma$ on the surface.

Is $\Gamma$ necessarily a smooth map to $\mathbb R^2$? Can I write, say, $D_0 \gamma = D_{\sigma^{-1} (p)} \sigma \circ D_0 \Gamma$ by the chain rule?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\sigma$ extends to a diffeomorphism between two open subsets of $R^3$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah no, how would I do this? Is there a theorem or something that I could use?

Comment: Do you know the constant rank theorem (at least for immersions  from open subsets of $R^2$ to $R^3$)? From your question it is hard to tell what you know and what you do not know in differential geometry. What book are you reading (if any)? The constant rank theorem will tell you that immersions $R^2\to R^3$ locally, after changes of coordinates in domain and codomain, have the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$. From this, you can easily construct an extension to a diffeomorphism of open subsets of $R^3$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am taking the first geometry course at my university, so I do not know much about differential geometry. I am not using a book and only consulting lecture notes, but we have proven the inverse function theorem and the implicit function theorem, if these are of any help.

Comment: Then read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016191/rank-theorem-proof?rq=1) question and answer. Can you finish on your own after that?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Right... I think I have a somewhat elementary solution. Let me write it up as an answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent definition for a regular surface is as such: $\Sigma$ is a regular surface iff for all $p \in \Sigma$ there exists an open neighborhood $T$ of $p$ in $\mathbb R^3$, an open neighborhood $W$ of the origin in $\mathbb R^3$, and a diffeomorphism $g: T \to W$ such that $g(T \cap \Sigma) = W \cap (\mathbb R^2 \times \{ 0 \})$.

Let's WLOG show that $\Gamma$ is smooth at $0 \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. For $t$ near $0$ (i.e. $\gamma(t)$ near $p$), we have
$$
\Gamma = \sigma^{-1} \circ \gamma = (g \circ \sigma)^{-1} \circ (g \circ \gamma).
$$
$g\circ\sigma$ is a smooth map in $\mathbb R^3$ landing in $\mathbb R^2$, so we can treat it as a smooth map to $\mathbb R^2$. As a map to $\mathbb R^2$, it's a local diffeomorphism at $\sigma^{-1}(p)$ since
$$
D_{\sigma^{-1}(p)}(g \circ \sigma) = \underbrace{D_p g}_{\text{isometry $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$}} \circ \underbrace{D_{\sigma^{-1}(p)} \sigma}_{\text{rank 2}}
$$
has rank $2$, so is invertible. Hence there exists a neighborhood about $\sigma^{-1} (p)$ on which $g \circ \sigma$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, i.e. $(g \circ \sigma)^{-1}$ is smooth in a neighborhood about $g(p)$.

Moreover, $g\circ \gamma$ is a composition of smooth maps, so is smooth. Hence, there is a neighborhood about $0$ in which $\Gamma$ is a composition of smooth maps, so is smooth.

Please let me know if you spot a mistake.